# How to specify packagenames with the Maven Javadoc plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

The Javadoc tool has a command-line option called "[packagenames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#synopsis)" which allows you to specify the package names you want to document. Does the maven javadoc plugin support this argument?

It seems that maven supports all the options as configuration properties, but packagenames is not an option, it's a command-line parameter and I can't see it listed on the maven javadoc plugin page.

The maven plugin does support the [subpackages](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/aggregate-mojo.html#subpackages) option, but this is different (it's recursive, whereas the packagenames argument is not).

How can I specify the packagenames argument with the Javadoc Maven plugin?

Answer (score 0):

There is an excludePackageNames option so you should be able to use that to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that but unfortunately there's a bug in the maven javadoc plugin that causes it to override the excludePackageNames with the subpackages option (the Oracle reference says that excludePackageNames overrides subpackages). Oh well.